# Mysql select statement with wildcard

Tags: sql, mysql, database, select

I have a mysql table EMPLOYEE

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name              | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start_salary      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| current_salary    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| designation       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-======------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, I would want to do a select statement like

```
SELECT (current_salary/start_salary) appraisal, * from EMPLOYEE;
```

But the above statement is not valid in mysql. This is not homework but a dummy eg. Is it possible to have an extra column along with all existing columns of a table using * as wildcard operator?

What is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes absolutely. Trick is simple, just put the wildcard FIRST.
That's it!

```
SELECT *, (current_salary/start_salary) appraisal from EMPLOYEE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Richard's answer is correct, but you **CAN** use * as last column too!

To specify *where* the ***** columns will appear (instead of first), all you need is give the table an *alias*, and then use `alias.*`, like this:

```
SELECT (E.current_salary/E.start_salary) appraisal, E.* from EMPLOYEE E;
```

In this case, i used E as alias, but it could be anything (emp, EMP).

The **E.** in current_salary and start_salary is optional, but highly recommended once you start using alias in your queries. In queries using multible tables (INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOINs), the alias is required if 2 or more tables have the same column name (otherwise, how would MySql know which table you want `name` or `ID` come from?)

Note that you can only use `alias.*` for tables whose column names are unique within the query (ie, no other table from the same query has columns with same names)

And * (without any alias, meaning "all columns from all tables") is only allowed if all column names from all tables are unique.